How to manually perform asymmetric encryption/decryption using tor keys
Suppose Alice owns an onion service and wants to verify she owns the service. One solution might be:

Alice encrypts her pub_key using her service's prv_key and sends to Bob.
Bob decrypts using the service's pub_key.
Bob can verify the decrypted value (pub_key) matches the pub_key he used to decrypt, so Bob trusts that Alice actually has the onion service's private key.

My question is twofold:

Is there an existing, better way to verify Alice's claim?
What are the actual terminal commands Alice and Bob would run to perform such a verification? (asymmetric encryption/decryption using tor keys)

(I have reviewed the advanced client-auth documentation but it does not address how asymmetric encryption/decryption can be manually done using tor keys.)

It was answered before here What encryption is actually used by tor circuits?  - you can use any tools supporting this algorithm of your choice. If you need to use a different method - just read tor's private key as a binary blob and use it corresponding to your needs
